# Use setting in session to set SSL enforcement

Tags: asp.net, session, ssl

I currently have the below code in my Global.ascx. It works fine when debugging, but on live site it causes issues related to session, it appears that the session is not available/created at certain points, so it blows up. The setting is stored in session (AppSettings.IsSslEnforced is retreived from session), so I have to read from there, right now we are thinking of perhaps putting in master page, but feel this would leave some requests vulnerable. Is there a better alternative?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
           if (!Request.IsSecureConnection && AppSettings.IsSslEnforced)
           {
               Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
           }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           LogManager.InsertErrorLog(ex);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute rather than Application_BeginRequest:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      try
      {
           if (!Request.IsSecureConnection && AppSettings.IsSslEnforced)
           {
               Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
           }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           LogManager.InsertErrorLog(ex);
      }
}
```

Comment: Looking at this article I see that this even is later in the flow, but may I ask, before I test, why you chose this event specifically? Thanks http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/

Comment: The event is called after Session_Start so the session object is available.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I'll test it and let you know if it works.